# How to execute the same loop for 1 hour in bash/ linux scripting?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to open and close some web pages with random intervals for an hour.

So far i have written the innards

```
FILE=webpages
TIMES=0
while test $TIMES -lt 10
do
    #Picks random line(Website) from FILE
    TEMPWEB=`shuf -n 1 $FILE`
    echo "Opening" $TEMPWEB
    #Opens TEMPWEB
    xdg-open $TEMPWEB
    sleep 10
    #Kills firefox
    ps -e | grep firefox | sed 's/\(.[0-9]*\).*/\1/' | xargs kill
    TIMES=$(($TIMES+1))
done
```

So I'm am missing the while condition.
I want something like:

```
TIMER = 0h 0m 0s
while( TIMER < 1 h)
   ....
done
```

Is this possible?

PS. what's the command to random number?

Comment: To get a random number, use `$RANDOM`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Surely. Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
START=`date +%s`
while [ $(( $(date +%s) - 3600 )) -lt $START ]; do
    ....
done
```

`date +%s` shows the current time in seconds since 1970. The loop computes the current date of an hour ago and checks if it exceeds the start time.

Comment: Doesn't that only gives true when its exactly 1h later ?

Answer (score 9):

One way you can do this is with signals and traps. Here's a simple example:

```
#!/bin/bash

me=$$

# Start a background process to signal us when the time has passed
(
        sleep 10
        kill -USR1 $me
) &

# When we recieve SIGUSR1, commit suicide
trap "kill $me" SIGUSR1

# Do stuff until we commit suicide
while [ 1 -eq 1 ]
do
        echo 'Hello!'
        sleep 1
done
```

The comments are self-explanetory (I hope). The first part kicks off a background process that just sleeps for a period of time (10 seconds in this example), and then when it wakes up sends SIGUSR1 to the originating process.

The shellscript catches this (with `trap`) and just issues a `kill` to its own PID, stopping the process.

The rest of it is just an infinite loop -- it's the `trap` that kills the script and terminates the loop.

Technically you don't need the trap in the example above: the background process could just issue `kill $me` directly, but I've included it for completeness as you can use it as a hook to do other things (e.g., if you don't want to die but set a flag and have the loop terminate naturally, or you have some clean-up to do before terminating).

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution :

```
#!/bin/bash

# function to display a number in a range
randrange() { echo $(( ( RANDOM % ($2 - $1 +1 ) ) + $1 )); }

# sleep 1 hour and keep backgrounded PID in a variable
sleep 3600 & _suicide_pid=$!

# while the process is UP
while kill &>/dev/null -0 $_suicide_pid; do
    # ----->8--- do what you want here <---8<-----
    sleep $(randrange 10 15) # random sleep in 10-15 range
done
```

Comment: This sound a bit complex for me `while kill &>/dev/null -0 $_suicide_pid; do`. Can u point me to any document explaining that? What does `-0` mean?

Comment: `kill -0 ` is just a littke hack to test if a PID exists. *

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based on [the one from thiton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8168457/1861492):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

STOP=`date -d 'next hour' +%s`
while [ $(date +%s) -lt $STOP ]; do
    date
    sleep 2
done
```

Also works fine inline:

```bash
STOP=`date -d 'next hour' +%s`; while [ $(date  +%s) -lt $STOP ]; do date; sleep 2; done
```